# How to add text to a textbox by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to have a button to the right of a textbox which when clicked would populate the textbox with a message.
I am assuming I can accomplish this with Javascript but the "onclick" method doesn't seem to work for me. I am probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript and HTML :

I am guessing what you need is, may be as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ButtonClick_Test()
{
document.getElementById("result").value= ' your text here';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
Click Here:<br/>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" name="no" onclick="ButtonClick_Test()"> 

<input type="text" id="result" size="20">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using jQuery(http://jquery.com/):

```
$('#buttonID').click(function() {
    $('#textareaID').val('Your text goes here');
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't mentioned Jquery.So this solution is not helpful.